# I need to know more about applying for a 10 years visa

Tags: united-kingdom, student-visa

I am applying for a study visa in the UK I can you tell me if I can do so on a 10 years visa

Comment: Welcome to the site Sandra davis, as your question is about applying for a visa for study, I migrated it to the site where they handle that kind of questions.

Comment: Hi, how long are you planning to study in the UK for?

Comment: You should note that there is now a total limit to the time possibly spent in the UK on a student visa between 2 -8 years, depending on the course of study and degree level attained. These limits were put in place to specifically stop perpetual students from attempting to qualify for ILR on the 10 years route via use of the student visa, in some cases without ever attaining a degree of any kind.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you already have a 10 year visitor visa? There is no possibility of applying for a study visa valid for 10 years. Maybe you could explain what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: There is no sufficient information to answer this question and hence can be closed.